# Print a Doubly Linked List in Reverse

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have a list that is dynamically created based off of user input. I can add strings, and I can remove strings, but I am at a loss on how to properly print this in reverse.

Example: 
input : First Second Last
output: Last Second First

I have tried a few things, and I have looked up what needs to be done, but I am having a tough time getting it correct.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// define a node for storage and linking
class node{
public:
    string name;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};

class linkedList{
public:
    linkedList() :top(NULL){}
    bool empty(){ return top == NULL; }
    node *getTop(){ return top; }
    void setTop(node *n){ top = n; }
    void add(string);
    int menu();
    void remove(string);
    ~linkedList();
    void reversePrint(); 
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const linkedList&); // default 

output is in-order print.
    private:
        node *top;
        node *end; 
    };

void main(){
    linkedList l;
    cout << l.empty() << endl;
    int option = 0;
    string s;
    bool go = true;
    while (go){
        option = l.menu();
        switch (option){
        case 1: cout << "enter a name: "; cin >> s; l.add(s); break;
        case 2: cout << "enter name to be deleted: "; cin >> s; l.remove(s); break;
        case 3: cout << l; break;
        case 4: cout << l.reversePrint(); break; // I am getting a Syntax error here
        case 5: cout << "exiting" << endl; go = false; break;
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    // l goes out of scope and calls ~linkedList()
}


void linkedList::reversePrint()
{

    node *start_ptr = NULL;
    node *current = start_ptr;
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *next = NULL;

    while (current){
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        current->prev = next;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }

}
```

Comment: if it's a doubly linked list, why don't you have a `getBottom` class method for `linkedList`? And to determine what order is *reverse* you need to indicate what order you put in the elements. To you insert them in the top or the bottom? (Linked lists don't have a natural definition for *top* and *bottom*.) Your `reversePrint` method actually changes the links in your linked list. You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: @lurker I am actually alright with changing the links in the list.

Comment: It appears to be a poorly named method. It says `reversePrint` which means you intend to print the list in reverse order. But are you reallly wanting to just reverse the list? Then it would more sensibly be called `reverse` or `reverseList`. You didn't answer my other questions.

Comment: @lurker I don't have a `getBottom` class because I didn't think it was necessary? I am just trying to take the list and print it in reverse. When the function is called in the main method I assumed I could do something like `cout >> l.reversePrint();` and it would reverse the list, and then print it. The order would just be based off of the stack, first in, first out.

Comment: I don't see where you are "printing" in that method. The beauty of a doubly linked list is that it can be traversed from either end to the other end. You shouldn't have to be swapping around `next` and `prev` pointers. If you want to go through the list in reverse, start at *bottom* and work your way to the *top* by following the *prev* pointers. That's why it's good to have a `getBottom` method (not *class*).

Comment: @lurker I think I understand a bit better now. All I need to do is make a function that returns the last node (the bottom), and then from there print out the previous pointer's node, then that pointer's previous node, etc and so on and so fourth?

Comment: For quick access to the bottom, it's pretty standard in a double linked list class to have easy access to the bottom pointer or the top pointer. Then you traverse the appropriate links backward through the list from that point. A doubly linked list should be designed to give you equivalent access either direction through the list.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide complete code (such as the implementation of linkedList::add()) so it's hard to give the correct answer...

According to your partial code, since the return type of reversePrint() is void, you can not cout it.
Therefore, in the switch block in main function should be:

```
case 4: l.reversePrint(); break;
```

I try to modify your code but not sure if it's correct since I don't have the code.

```
void linkedList::reversePrint()
{
    node *current = end;
    while (current){
        cout << current->name << " ";
        current = current->prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be more than happy to share the rest of the code I have. I was trying to give what was only necessary. I wasn't sure if the rest of the code might be helpful. Would you like me to post it to the question?